# Charging the user myself, without having them to enter in their card details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, payment, stripe-payments

I'm working with stripe. I'm confused: is the only way to charge the user (customer) by showing them the Stripe pop up where they enter in their bank card details and click ok? Is there any way to charge them **without** having them doing that themselves, let's say, by a cron task which is run once a month on **my web server** where they're registered?

I'm guessing, there should be a way to do so but they have to do that **manually at least once**, for the second time their card details are saved at Stripe server and I, indeed, can charge them automatically, is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do subscriptions, which is a whole Stripe topic in and of itself.  You may want to check out Pete Keen's blog (and book).  A relevant entry is here - https://www.petekeen.net/using-stripe-checkout-for-subscriptions

This gem may also be helpful - https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku

Comment: please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602655/subscriptions-in-stripe