# Subscriptions in stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I've read this https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions but don't really understand the idea of subscriptions in respect to implementation.

What I need is being to charge the user but the amount of charge is to be calculated by myself because I have a special algorithm for it. So this code:

```
 # create a plan - once!
  Stripe::Plan.create(
    :amount => 2000,
    :interval => 'month',
    :name => 'Amazing Gold Plan',
    :currency => 'cad',
    :id => 'gold'
  )


# every month? or also once?

maybe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(....)
unless maybe_customer
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :card => token,
    :plan => "gold",
    :email => "payinguser@example.com"
  )
end
```

**When (how often)** do I have to run it: only **once** or every month (`:interval => 'month'`)?

**If every month**, I'll run it as a cron task. But how to get the user to enter in their credit card details? Or do they have to enter them in only the first time, then I save them and then will be able to re-use them?

**UPDATE**:

1. Since it's a subscription, it's to occur automatically. Does that mean that it's **completely** automatic for the user? **Or** do they have to enter their card details into the pop up from Stripe **once** and from that moment on it'll become automatic for the user, meaning they won't have to enter their bank card details anymore, they will be charged automatically by stripe each month later?
2. How do charge the user zero cents as a monthly pay if some (my) condition is true and using `account_balance`? From this https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing  I don't understand how to do that.
3. I don't see any difference between a subscription and just charging a customer like if it were the normal payments. If both cases I have to run a code once a month on the server. What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but the only thing I could understand clearly from your question was that you need to know how to execute one-time payments rather than proper subscriptions.

Reading [the link you've shared](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions), I've gathered that you should be able to set an `interval_count` option for the number of months (or intervals) after which the customer is charged. So setting `interval_count` to 0 ***should*** make the payment happen only once.

Also, this is from the same page:

> Customer objects can also store a credit card, which is how they'll be
>   billed later on.

In other words, yes - the customer enters his/her card details the first time. You can (optionally ?) save the card info in the Customer object.

Comment: `after which the customer is charged` - how is the customer charged: do they have to enter in their card details (in the pop up) each month? Or can I run it on my web server so the user (customer) doesn't have to do anything?

Comment: Read my updated response and, more importantly, the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question, the 1st questions is clearer now.